# Jekyll sees changes in CSS, doesn't regenerate 'em

Tags: css, ruby, jekyll

I'm running a Linux VM (Vagrant) on a Windows host and trying to get my one-page Jekyll app to work.

I don't have a config file. 
I started Jekyll by running

```
jekyll serve -H 0.0.0.0 --force_polling
```

When I make changes to `default.html`, it's changed in `_site/index.html`. When I make changes to `main.css`, nothing changes in `_site/main.css` source code.

When running with `--verbose` the output says it catches changes in CSS file, it just doesn't update it for some reason.

```
Regenerating: 1 file(s) changed at 2017-07-13 20:47:37          
Rendering: index.html
Pre-Render Hooks: index.html
Rendering Liquid: index.html
Rendering Markup: index.html
Rendering Layout: index.html
...done in 0.053759762 seconds.
```

Why?